# VB.net Selecting files and folders in a folder

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to select the files and folders inside a folder to zip up, but what it seems to be doing is selecting all the folders up to the folder i've selected and the files in the final folder but not the folders in there and zipping them up. So for example in  tbFolder I have the string: "C:\Users\tomb\Desktop\DeOld\Mota7" I want to select this folder and zip up the entire contents of this folder, images and all. But whats happening is the following:

[image]

Its creating the folder structure up to the folder i want zipped and adding just the files in side this and not the folders. I'm guessing I need to tweak the line:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryToZip)
```

Here is the entire code:

```
Private Sub btnCreate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click

        Dim ZipFile As String = "C:\Releases\" & drpService.Text & "-" & DateTime.Now.ToString("YYmmDD") & ".zip"
        Dim DirectoryToZip As String = tbFolder.Text
        Dim filenames As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryToZip)

        Using zip As ZipFile = New ZipFile
            zip.AddFiles(filenames)
            zip.Save(ZipFile)
        End Using


    End Sub
```

Comment: Wichita zip library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=VB-Examples&referringTitle=Examples), there is an example on their site to add an entire directory

```
zip.AddDirectory(DirectoryToZip, "RootFolderInZip");
```